# $.post function for login form in lightbox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, I have a login form set in a lightbox. I want that when users click on submit, a function check if the username and password are correct before refreshing and go to the member page. It should also show the errors in the lightbox.

I have a problem with the jQuery part more particularly with the $.post function.

jQuery code:

```
 $('#Connection form').submit('Connection',function(){
var Username = $('#UsernameConnection').val();

if(Username=="")
{   
    $('#UsernameConnection').css('border-color','red');
    $('.ErrorUsernameConnection').text('Error 1');
    Username = "Empty Field";
}else

if(Username=="Invalid")
{
    $('#UsernameConnection').css('border-color','orange');
    $('.ErrorUsernameConnection').text('Error 2');
    Username = "Invalid field";
}

var Password = $('#Password Connection').val();

if(Password =="")
{   
    $('#Password Connection').css('border-color','red');
    $('.ErrorPassword Connection').text('Error 3');
    Password = "Empty field";
}
    if((Username==true)&&(Password==true))
    {           
        $.post('fonctions/connection.php',{VALUE1:VALUE2},function(connection)
        {
            $('.ConnectionError').text(connection);

            if(connection=="ok")
            {
                return true;
            }else
            {
                return false;
            }
        });     
    }else
    {   
        return false;
    }
    });
        });
```

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Connection']))
{   
     all the verifying function goes here.
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="Connection">
    <div class="formConnection">
    <form method="POST" autocomplete="off" name="Connection">
        <label for="Connection">Username:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="UsernameConnection" id="UsernameConnection"/><br/>
        <span class="ErrorUsernameConnection"></span><br/>
        <label for="Connection">Password:</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="PasswordConnection" id="PasswordConnection"/>
        <span class="ErrorPasswordConnection"></span><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/><label>Remember me</label><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="Connection" value="Log In" id="Connection" class="LogIn"/>       
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question are:

- Is `$.post` the right function for this? If yes,:
- Because the script only starts when users click in the submit button, is it necessary to create a new `var` in the jQuery just for the submit button?
- Is the `if(isset($_POST['Connection']))` part in the php necessary in this case or can I just put the function right away?
- What should `VALUE1` and `VALUE2` be for this to work?

Comment: `$('#Connection form')` won't match anything on your page.

Comment: @arxanas it will match a form inside a container with id Connection: http://jsfiddle.net/tk4x3/

Comment: @arxanas and myself: And that's when I checked OP's HTML, I said nothing! ;)

Comment: @arxanas he doesn't have a form with id "Connection"

Comment: @rsplak And there are none, so it won't match anything.

Comment: @PeterPajchl Whoops, I meant `form[name=Connection]`. Edited.

Comment: Actually there is, I didn't put it because it didn't seem relevant. Will add it here right now ^^

Comment: Script works well except that I can't get it to start the verifying part when user click on submit. Everything else, works find.

Comment: where do you get these variables `if((Username==true)&&(Password==true))` ? from the code provided, they are always undefined therefore, your post will never execute

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
$('#Connection form').submit('Connection',function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: { name: "John", password: "Boston" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });

 });
```

Basically, you can just serialize your form and post it to the page.  Have the page send back a message (success or fail, 1 or 0) and then do something with that data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating matters. You just want to post a form via AJAX—the easiest way to do this is as follows:

```
$('#login-form').submit(function() {
    $.post('login.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
        // do something on success or failure here
    });
    return false;
});
```

Have your `login.php` echo a JSON object, or `true` or `false`, and display any errors in your lightbox or whatever.